# insert multiple rows along with static values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, rows

I'm very new to SQL. More familiar with procedural programming

I currently have local variables such as names that change within a loop. However, I also execute a function that returns many rows. Right now I loop through each row to insert the values into a result table.

How do I put date in a table with values (name, cname, val1, val2)
when I have multiple rows?

example case:

```
set @name = 'test'
select cname, val1, val2 from myfunc(@name)
```

returns:

```
-----------------------
| cname | val1  | val2 |
------------------------
|'atest'| 1.3   | 42.0 |
|'btest'| 1.58  | 6.87 |
------------------------
```

and I'd like result table (@restable) to be:

```
-----------------------------
name  | cname | val1  | val2 |
-----------------------------
'test'|'atest'| 1.3   | 42.0 |
'test'|'btest'| 1.58  | 6.87 |
------------------------------
```

Note I still need @restable for more statements after this operation.

Comment: `select @name, cname, val1, val2 from myfunc(@name)`

Comment: If you find yourself using loops in SQL you're probably doing it wrong. Loops are natural when you're used to procedural programming but with SQL you'll get much better performance if you can teach yourself to think in sets. It isn't easy but at the simplest level you can think of it as venn diagrams of sets of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @t table(cname varchar(10),val1 decimal(10,2),val2 decimal(10,2))
insert into @t (cname,val1,val2) values ('atest',1.3,42.0)
insert into @t (cname,val1,val2) values ('btest',1.58,6.87)
select * from @t

declare @tt table(name varchar(10), cname varchar(10),val1 varchar(10),val2 decimal(10,2))
insert into @tt(name,cname,val1,val2)
select (select 'test')name, cname,val1,val2  from @t
select * from @tt
```

Comment: Thanks! This did answer my question, I failed when trying to insert because I included 'values' but this post shows you can just directly insert into.

Answer (score 1):

I know this works with a table
Not sure about a function
If the function is returning a table this should work

```
set @name = 'test'
select @name as [name], cname, val1, val2 from myfunc(@name)
```

Comment: Hi Blam. That seems to give the right result, but doing "insert into @restable values" seems to fail to put that set into the table.

Comment: Show the insert.  Because I don't think you should have the term 'values' in that insert.

Comment: You're right, I should not have had the insert, and noticed from mohan111's post that it was not included.